# How to remove AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport

Tags: asp.net

Many of my url's on my site  www.mysite.com/Display.aspx?ID=128

gets displayed to users as

www.mysite.com/Display.aspx?ID=128&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

How can I remove AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport.

I understand it has to do something with cookie in web.config, but where? And what would be the implications if I remove that. How to remove?

Answer (score 15):

To remove this, change the **cookieless** property of sessionState in your web.config to *false*.

e.g.

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="20" />
```

When cookieless is set to *autodetect*, the framework generates the AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport querystring to determine if the client has cookie support. If the client does not have cookies enabled, ASP.Net will store the users Session Id directly in the URL.

[An application using ASP.Net cookieless session support http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/Aa479314.cookieless01(en-us,MSDN.10).gif](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/Aa479314.cookieless01(en-us,MSDN.10).gif)

*An application using ASP.Net cookieless session support*

This potentially opens up your application to session hijacking and might be considered a risk. A better option may be to disable this feature and alert your users that they will need to have cookies enabled to use your application.

For more a more detailed look at this, read [Cookieless ASP.Net by Dino Esposito](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479314.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: This fixes the /(t5......55)/ before the Home.aspx issue. But not the 302 redirect.

Answer (score 0):

...or **if you don't want cookieless sessions**, check if you have the following property in your `<sessionState>` node: `cookieless="AutoDetect"`
If you **want** to use cookies, but **don't want** that querystring attribute, remove `cookieless="AutoDetect"`