# .net site all pages do a 302 redirect with AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport

Tags: session-state, http-status-code-302, cookieless, anonymousidentification

First let me say that I did see this article:
[How to remove AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045283/how-to-remove-aspxautodetectcookiesupport)
However it seems like it fixes the url issue, but **not** the 302 AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport issue.
I've also read just about every other article on the web about this issue.
I could really use some help here.

This is my web.config

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="6600" />

<membership defaultProvider="MySqlMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add connectionStringName="SimpleTickConnection" applicationName="TheaterSales" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Hashed" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="15" minRequiredPasswordLength="7" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression="" name="MySqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <anonymousIdentification enabled="true" cookieless="AutoDetect" cookieProtection="All" cookieRequireSSL="false" cookieSlidingExpiration="true" />
```

To replicate the issue:
http://web-sniffer.net/
and use your url

[alt text http://img28.imageshack.us/img28/8615/issue.gif](http://img28.imageshack.us/img28/8615/issue.gif)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I researched on: anonymousIdentification

I removed

```
cookieless="AutoDetect"
```

And now the object moved error went away